# How can I serialize my ViewModel to XML and send it to a remote server?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, http, serialization

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application in which I am trying to serialize my ViewModel and send it to a remote, third-party server for data processing. I am not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, but below is the code that I have tried.

Firstly, here is the `POST` method in my controller in which I am trying to serialize the ViewModel and send it to the remote server:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Transmission t)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "";
            ViewBag.OtherMessage = "";

            try
            {
                //serialize the ViewModel
                XmlResult xrs = new XmlResult(t);
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xrs.ToString());
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(); //the memory stream to be used to save the xdoc
                XmlActionResult xar = new XmlActionResult(xdoc);
                xdoc.Save(stream);
                //xrs.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);

                //POST the data to the external URL
                var url = "theUrl";
                var PostData = xar;


                var Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                Req.ContentType = "application/xml";
                Req.Method = "POST";
                Req.Timeout = 60000;
                Req.KeepAlive = false;


                //build the string to send
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string line; 
                    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(line);
                    }
                    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
                    Req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;


                    using (Stream requestStream = Req.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                        requestStream.Close();
                    }

                   using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)Req.GetResponse())
                    {
                        ViewBag.OtherMessage = response.ToString();
                        return View("Error"); //TODO: change this to success when I get the 500 error fixed
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = ex.Message;
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see above, I am using two classes, called `XmlActionResult` and `XmlResult`, respectively. The `XmlResult` class is being used to serialize the ViewModel. Here is the implementation of the `XmlResult` class:

```
public class XmlResult : ActionResult
    {
        private object objectToSerialize;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="XmlResult"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="objectToSerialize">The object to serialize to XML.</param>
        public XmlResult(object objectToSerialize)
        {
            this.objectToSerialize = objectToSerialize;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the object to be serialized to XML.
        /// </summary>
        public object ObjectToSerialize
        {
            get { return objectToSerialize; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the object that was passed into the constructor to XML and writes the corresponding XML to the result stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The controller context for the current request.</param>
        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if (objectToSerialize != null)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
                context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "xml";
                xs.Serialize(context.HttpContext.Response.Output, objectToSerialize);
            }
        }
    }
```

After the `XmlResult` class serializes the ViewModel, I am attempting to create a `XDocument` using the `XmlActionResult` class. Here is the implementation of the `XmlActionResult` class:

```
public sealed class XmlActionResult : ActionResult
    {
        private readonly XDocument _document;

        public Formatting Formatting { get; set; }
        public string MimeType { get; set; }

        public XmlActionResult(XDocument document)
        {
            if (document == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("document");

            _document = document;

            // Default values
            MimeType = "text/xml";
            Formatting = Formatting.None;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = MimeType;

            using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8) { Formatting = Formatting })
                _document.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
```

I believe this is where my first problem lies. I want to create a `XDocument` from the serialized ViewModel object -- `t` in this case -- using the `XmlResult` class, but I am getting an error saying "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. " This tells me that the `XDocument` class is having a problem parsing the serialized ViewModel object. What have I done wrong here?

Next, I am trying to save the `XDocument` (after it has been successfully created) in a `MemoryStream`. The idea is to build a `byte` array from a `StringBuilder` object that is accessing the `XDocument` that is saved in the `MemoryStream` via a `StreamReader`, and send that to the remote server via the `HttpWebRequest` object. However, I haven't gotten this far yet, thanks to the above error.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm willing to change this entire approach if I need to. I'm not certain the latter part will work even if I get the first part working, so any advice will be heeded. Thank you.

**Update: Further Information about Exception**

The exception is being thrown at this line:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xrs.ToString());
```

The `innerException` is null.
The `Message` is "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Comment: *Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.* - can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception?  At what line the exception being thrown?  Can you reduce your question to an [mcve]?

Comment: @dbc Sure. Hang on.

Comment: @dbc Further information about the exception has been provided.

Comment: put xrs.ToString() into a variable to see what the XDocument is trying to parse.

Comment: I'm also confused about a lot of this code.  You are using XmlResult from MvcContrib just to serialize your viewmodel?  That's doing a whole bunch of stuff you shouldn't need to simply serialize and send to a 3rd party system.  I'd hide everything about that third party system in a gateway class and in it's own project and just reference it in your controller action.  Also couldn't you just tag the view model as Serializable and then call the XmlSerializer directly?

Comment: Result classes are used to send information to the view, but your controller action doesn't send anything back to the view except in the case of an error.

Comment: @Fran Thanks for the advice. I'm new to this, so I'm learning. Do you know where I could see an example of calling the XmlSerializer directly? The ViewModel is marked as Serializable, by the way.

Comment: Have you debugged to determine the value of `xrs.ToString()`?  According to the [docs for `ActionResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx) its implementation of `ToString()` is *(Inherited from Object.)* which means it should just return the type name.

Comment: The XmlResult does it, it just writes to the http response stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Transmission t)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "";
        ViewBag.OtherMessage = "";

        try
        {

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Transmission));
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, t);
                var contentData = sw.ToString();
                var httpContent = new StringContent(contentData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("", httpContent);
                ViewBag.OtherMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return View("Error"); //TODO: change this to success when I get the 500 error fixed
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. I just had to make some changes so that the XML encoding doesn't appear in the XML data, but this is correct. Thank you. This is tremendously helpful.

Comment: @Fran was right. I was doing lots of things that the XmlSerializer would do for me. I misunderstood what the `XmlResult` and `XmlActionResult` classes were doing. It turns out that I don't need those at all.